# Using hstore with CakePHP on Heroku causes PDOException

Tags: php, cakephp, heroku, hstore

I am trying to store data on a Heroku Postgres DB with the hstore engine enabled. On Heroku´s site everything works fine. What troubles me is the PHP in my backend. I use the [POMM converters](https://github.com/chanmix51/Pomm/blob/master/Pomm/Converter/PgHStore.php)

This is what I basically use in my controller:

```
$this->loadModel('Channel');
$pgHStore = new PgHStore();
$data = $pgHStore->toPg(array('channel_id' => 1, 'title' => 'Test'));
$this->Channel->save(array('name' => 'test', 'attributes' => $data));
```

It just throws a PDOException:

```
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[XX000]: Internal error: 7 ERROR:  Syntax error near '$' at position
LINE 1: ..."channel" ("name", "attributes") VALUES ('test', '($hst$"ch...
                                                            ^
```

Has anyone accomplished this before with PHP and PDO? I am sure! But how? Where am I mistaken?

Comment: PgHStore is not a serializer to insert data as a string. It is intended to manage input / output directly from / to Postgres in a HStore column type. Not sure CakePHP supports this though. Why not use Pomm directly ?

Comment: @greg I don´t use it directly because I do not want to reinvent the wheel just to use a specific datatype. As I understand the PgHStore functions they do not have any other purpose than converting data (arrays, strings, etc.) to the appropriate hstore format so they should be sufficient IMHO. The question is why PDO stumbles.

Comment: It is actually not a problem from PDO since Pomm uses PDO as well. The problem here is Cake. It sees the data you give it as a string and tries to save it as is. Could you post your table structure and dump the full SQL query as issued ?